# Can't Rake Database "Undefined method "each" For SQLite"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, digital-ocean

Hello I am just getting started putting up a test database. I am using the preloaded rails environment from digital-ocean if that helps anything.

So I have just cloned my application from github and went rake db:create. When I did that it says there is an undefined method each for SQLite. I am not using sqlite though? I have specified PostgreSQL as the adapter.

I am a noob so sorry If this is a dumb question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also If I type rails db then I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed SQLite using gem uninstall sqlite3 then restarted the server. Everything started to work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> rake db:create

Not

> rake:db create

Comment: Sorry, that was just a misspelling. The error is still there when I do rake db:create